# Alternate Version of Schwarz Lemma

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle

Let $f$ be analytic on $\vert z \vert \leq R$ with

$$\vert f(z) \vert \leq M$$

on $\vert z \vert = R$. Prove then that

$$\vert f(z)-f(0) \vert \leq \frac{2M\vert z \vert}{R}.$$

I know by the maximum principle that

$$\max_{\vert z \vert \leq R}\{f(z)\} \leq M$$

Since the maximum on the closure is the same as the maximum on the boundary, thus

$$\vert f(0) \vert \leq M$$

as $0 \in \overline{B_R(0)}$. But Then I get stuck.. any hints greatly appreciated.

Comment: One thing to be a little careful about is saying "holomorphic on $|z|\le R$, because in most reasonable interpretations this requires holomorphy on an open _containing_ that closed disk. Schwarz' lemma only needs holomorphy on $|z|<R$ and extending _continuously_ to the boundary. It makes the proof a little more fussy, but, yeah, the idea is still the same, absolutely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can proceed as in the [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma#Proof) of the “usual” Schwarz Lemma:
$$
 h(z) = \frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z}
$$
has a removable singularity at $z=0$, and $|h(z)| \le \frac{2M}{R}$ for $|z| =R$. Now apply the maximum modulus principle to $h$.

Comment: I thought the Schwarz Lemma is what I was trying to prove.

Comment: That could be the case, perhaps..in the exercise however it simply put "use the maximum pricinple to prove the Schwarz Lemma" number 28: https://www.uh.edu/nsm/_docs/math/preliminary_syllabi/preliminary_samples/1_Complex_Variable_Prelim_SampleProblems.pdf

Comment: can I write $\vert h(z) \vert:=\frac{1}{\vert z \vert} \vert f(z)-f(0) \vert$? And multiply both sides by $\vert z \vert$?

Comment: So, by the maximum principle, does $\vert h(z) \vert \leq \frac{2M}{R}$ for all $z \in \overline{B_R(0)}$

Comment: question what was that original $g(z)$ u defined it has a $f(Rz)-f(0)$ term to it. And you used the regular Schwarz to prove hitting that $g(z)$ with it.

Comment: @HossienSahebjame: https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4481703/revisions